# After using django-import-export, Django triggers an IntegrityError exception when inserting new records through the admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

Django tries to add a new record with an existing `id` value, it doesn't realize about the 800 new records I inserted into the database via [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export).

Is there a quick workaround I can use to tell Django to start adding records with the last available `id` number?